# Problem setting the resolution

Tags: display, resolution

I have a 1360x768 tv that I am currently using for my display and whenever i set it too that resolution it is zoomed in and cuts off the sides. The top, bottom and right side of the screen are cut of slightly and the left side is cut off by 1/10 or more of the display.

[Pictures for clarity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg53T.jpg)

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the major problems of using a TV as a monitor: they are lousy at telling the computer what exact resolution they have and at following orders if the computer tells them what to do...

As we don't have the exact specs of your TV, you should look up "overscan" or "overzoom" or "zoom" in your TV manual and then turn that feature off on your TV.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will definitely look in to that. This has been bugging me since i installed Ubuntu a few days ago.